# NPM insists on using the wrong registry URL

Tags: npm, registry

Using NPM to install dependencies, including one that is stored in Verdaccio running locally.

Somehow NPM is stuck attempting to load the Verdaccio dependency from localhost even though the command to install from the corrected location has been run `npm install --save --registry http://CORRECT-URL ...`

Using `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json` and removing the dependency from `package.json`, then running the install again - still DOES NOT WORK.  Every time the install command completes, `package-lock.json` STILL uses `localhost` to resolve the registry.

Removing localhost from `~/.npmrc` and running `npm set registry http://CORRECT-URL` also didn't help.

Please help.  Where is NPM remembering `localhost` and insisting on using it???

**UPDATE** - Using `npm install -ddd`

Attempted to use `npm install -ddd` to see where npm is picking up the package.  The output shows the CORRECT-URL, but when it is done, `package-lock.json` still lists `localhost`.

Note all of the following:

- Removed all references to the PACKAGE from `package.json` and `package-lock.json`
- Verified no references to `localhost` in either file
- Removed `node_modules/PACKAGE_DIR` with `rm -rf`
- Removed PACKAGE from `node_modules/.package-lock.json`
- Searched for `.npmrc` and `npmrc` in the build tree and found two empty files:

  - node/node_modules/npm/docs/public/configuring-npm/npmrc
  - node/node_modules/npm/.npmrc
- ~/.npmrc has 2 entries for the CORRECT_URL in the following forms:

  - //:/:_authToken="<AUTH_TOKEN>"
  - registry=http://:/

Comment: run `npm install -ddd --registry xxx` to check which registry is hitting , npm only takes the registry from 3 locations, the `.npmrc` in home folder, the root of your project or via `--registry`

Comment: Thanks for the `-ddd`.  The output from running `npm install -ddd` does not show `localhost` anywhere, yet that's still what ends up in `package-lock.json`.  I'll update the description with the details.  Is there some place that NPM might be translating the hostname instead of using it as-given on the command-line?

Comment: I still don't fully get it, does `http://CORRECT-URL` is a verdaccio server? it is an IP? which version of npm? maybe you could describe a reproducible example. I've never seen such scenario so I have the feeling some step here is missing. The 4th step in your list is a typo? remove lock file withing node_modules?

Comment: I'm trying to be careful to avoid publishing certain details - apologies for any confusion.  `http://CORRECT-URL` is of the form `http://verdaccio:4873`.  If my package were named `my-custom-package`, the forth step is `rm -rf node_modules/my-custom-package`.  I'll try to come up with a reproducable example, perhaps using github and docker.  Note that using `strace` on the npm process does not show it loading `localhost:4873` from any config files.  NODE version is 14.17.0 (is that npm 6.14.13?) - using maven-frontend-plugin to do most of the work.

Comment: Is there a way to setup a mirror or proxy that could be doing this?

Answer (score 2):

Stumbled upon this post while trying to debug the exact same situation.  What ended up solving this for me was to blow out package-lock, run npm rebuild, then npm install --registry .  Hope this helps someone in the future!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32780916)

Comment: Deleting node_modules and running npm rebuild seems to have done the trick. Thanks a lot for the update.